# argparse: require optional arguments to precede positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python script that wraps the openssh client binary, and needs to parse arguments in the same way. I'm using argparse.

With ssh, this means conect to host, login as "a", and run "ls".

```
ssh -la host ls
```

While this means connect to host and run "ls -la":

```
ssh host ls -la
```

argparse treats these as the same. Is there an idiomatic way to tell argparse that optional arguments must precede positional arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('-l', '--login')
p.add_argument('host')
p.add_argument('cmd', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
print p.parse_args('-la server ls'.split())
print p.parse_args('server ls -la'.split())
```

Result:

```
Namespace(cmd=['ls'], host='server', login='a')
Namespace(cmd=['ls', '-la'], host='server', login=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you trying to accomplish fits pretty well in `argparse` sub-commands concept. Take a look at it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: "host" isn't a fixed value here, it's a positional argument that could have any value. Handing off to a subparser would have to occur after the first positional argument and not after a specific command. I don't see a way to do that.